# manage multiple github repos from the same system and different user names

Tags: git, github

Background:
i have a system, i use the same for both hobby and office projects. I have a different github repo for both places. Ideally i would want to commit with different user names. 
Hence i create repos and local user names: `git config --local user.name "Local Name"`

The trouble arises while pushing the same ssh keys do not work for both the repos. In case if i change the ssh key for one repo, it creates me a trouble to push to the other repo using the same ssh keys. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Linux / Unix, you can configure your `.ssh/config` file to point to 2 different identies

```
Host foo foo.example.com
Hostname foo.example.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo_rsa

Host bar bar.example.org
Hostname bar.example.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bar_rsa
```

Comment: could you please elaborate, i am a new user.

Comment: Essentially what the config above is stating then when you connect using Unix/Linux to a server, using the above config you can use two different ssh keys for server.

Comment: but how do i integrate it with git repos?

Comment: There is nothing to integrate beyond this. For each git repo if you perform a call like `git pull` as each repo has a different site, a different identity file will be used by Unix